# How to write a LESS expression?

Tags: css, less

Here's my LESS statements:

```
@colorWhite: #FFFFFF;
@colorBlack : #000000;
@opacityNormalFill: 0.2; 
@opacityNormalLabel: 0.75;
.colorWithAlpha(@color, @alpha)
{
   @colorWithAlpha: rgba( red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @alpha );
}
```

if I write both background-color and color as this:

```
.button {
   .colorWithAlpha(@colorBlack, @opacityNormalFill);
   background-color: @colorWithAlpha;
   .colorWithAlpha(@colorWhite, @opacityNormalLabel);
   color: @colorWithAlpha;
}
```

The output will be:

```
.button {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

I have to write it like this:

```
.button {
   .colorWithAlpha(@colorBlack, @opacityNormalFill);
   background-color: @colorWithAlpha;
}
.button {
   .colorWithAlpha(@colorWhite, @opacityNormalLabel);
   color: @colorWithAlpha;
}
```

It will output correctly:

```
.button { 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.button {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your var `@colorWithAlpha` is limitted to your function `.colorWithAlpha`. If you try to use a global var, it will modifie all your code. You should pass the part to set this color in the function params like this :

```
@colorWhite: #FFFFFF;
@opacityNormalFill: 0.2; 
@opacityNormalLabel: 0.75;
@colorBlack : #000000;
.colorWithAlpha(@color, @alpha, @property)
{
   @{property} : rgba( red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @alpha );
}
```

And when you use it :

```
.button {
    .colorWithAlpha(@colorBlack, @opacityNormalFill, background-color);
    .colorWithAlpha(@colorWhite, @opacityNormalLabel, color);
}
```

Comment: LESS: Unrecognised input ?

Comment: have you the latest less version ? Show me the complete error

Comment: Yes, the latest vesion.

Comment: Warning 16 Missing a colon (':') between the property and value in the "(property) : (value)" declaration.

Comment: Ok, it seems works whithout quotes on property name in function params. Try withoutquotes on background-color and color

Comment: I use Visual Studio, it still has the same error 'Unrecognised input' at  '@{property}', if I use '@property', no errors but no output at the same time.

Comment: Visual Studio is known to give false errors an warnings since its parser does not support latest Less features. Notice however that despite the warning the code *is* compiled just fine.

Answer (score 0):

less doesn't set global variables. You should be using the mixin as a nested style, not as a function.

Like:

```
.colorWithAlpha(@bgcolor, @color, @alpha)
{
   background-color: rgba( red(@bgcolor), green(@bgcolor), blue(@bgcolor), @alpha );
   color: rgba( red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @alpha );
}
```

Then:

```
.button {
   .colorWithAlpha(@colorBlack, @colorWhite, @opacityNormalLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature):

> All variables defined in a mixin are visible and can be used in caller's scope (**unless the caller defines its own variable with the same name**).

Since your first `.colorWithAlpha` expansion does already define the `@colorWithAlpha` variable inside the `.button`, the second `.colorWithAlpha` call has no effect. (See [#1892](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1892) for more details).

So you need either to isolate each expansion in its own scope:

```
.button {
    .colorWithAlpha(@colorBlack, @opacityNormalFill);
    background-color: @colorWithAlpha;
    & { // <- begin new scope
        .colorWithAlpha(@colorWhite, @opacityNormalLabel);
        color: @colorWithAlpha;
    }
}
```

Or use the solution suggested in @throrin19's answer.

## ---

And btw., to change color opacity use [fade](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade) function, i.e. *you don't need this mixin at all* and your snippet can be simplified to:

```
@opacityNormalFill:  20%;
@opacityNormalLabel: 75%;

.button {
   background-color: fade(#000, @opacityNormalFill);
   color:            fade(#fff, @opacityNormalLabel);
}
```